# Congruence subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

It is known that the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_p$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, that is the kernel of the epimorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ (with $p$ a prime number), is a free group.

Have you a reference for this result?

Comment: Not true, $\Gamma_2$ has an element of order 2.

Comment: Group-theoretically, though, you can proceed as follows: $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cong C_4\ast_{C_2} C_6$, and the subgroup will be free iff it is torsion-free, that is, avoids all elements of orders $2$, $3$, $4$, and $6$.  All of these have a handful of standard forms in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, so just check if any are congruent to the identity mod $p$.

Comment: The criterion given by Steve D is for example proved in Serre's *Trees*, paragraph 4.3.

Comment: @SteveD I suggest you post your comment as an answer, then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\Gamma_p$ is  torsion free (which will be the case provided $p > 2$), then it acts freely and properly diconstinuously on the upper half-plane $H$, and so is identified with the fundamental group of the quotient
$H/\Gamma_p$.  But this quotient is a punctured Riemann surface, and hence its $\pi_1$ is free.  Thus $\Gamma_p$ is free.  (And it is not difficult to compute the number of generators, since this is just a matter of determining the genus and number of punctures of $H/\Gamma_p$.)

Comment: Another way to find the number of generators is with Euler characteristic: $\chi(SL(2,\mathbb{Z}))= 1/4 + 1/6 - 1/2 = -1/6$. Now $\Gamma_p$ has index $|SL(2,p)|=p(p-1)(p+1)$, and so $\chi(\Gamma_p)=-p(p-1)(p+1)/6$.  Thus the rank of $\Gamma_p$ is $1+p(p-1)(p+1)/6$.

Answer (score 1):

We can also argue as follows. As in Matt E's answer we first need to begin by observing that $\Gamma(p)$ is torsion-free once $p \ge 3$; in particular this means its intersection with the center $-1 \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial, so it injects into the modular group $\Gamma = PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Next, recall that $\Gamma$ can be written as the free product $C_2 \ast C_3$ (a proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197537/prove-that-psl2-mathbbz-is-free-product-of-c-2-and-c-3)). By the [Kurosh subgroup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem) every subgroup of $\Gamma$ must be a free product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}, C_2$, and $C_3$, and among these the ones which are torsion-free are precisely the free products of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. So we get that every torsion-free subgroup of $\Gamma$, and hence of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, is free.

One can work quite explicitly with finite index subgroups of $\Gamma$ by drawing certain [graphs of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_groups) / [dessins d'enfant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant); see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/drawing-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/) for some nice pictures.