# Prove that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is free product of $C_2$ and $C_3$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

Prove that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})=C_2 \star C_3$.

Now $C_2 \star C_3=\langle a,b\ |\ a^2, b^3 \rangle$ i.e. the free product.

But how do I show that presentation of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ act on the set of irrational numbers via $$\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \cdot z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$

- Show that $A=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $B= \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$ generate $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.
- For convenience, let $C=AB$. Notice that $B$ is an order-two element and $C$ an order-three element. Therefore, it defines an epimorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3 \twoheadrightarrow \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.
- Let $w$ be a non-trivial alternating word written over $\{ B \}$ and $\{ C, C^{-1} \}$. Now, according to what $w$ looks like, find an irrational $z$ such that $w(z) \neq z$. In particular, $w \neq 1$.
- Conclude that our morphism $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ turns out to be an isomorphism.

More information and references can be found in [An elementary application of ping-pong lemma](https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/an-elementary-application-of-ping-pong-lemma/).