# Unique factorization of elements in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, modular-group

It is well know that the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the matrices $S= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $T= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. In particular, we have that

$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})= \langle S,T \mid S^4, ()^3=^2 \rangle $.

The presentation implies that for every $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ there exist a finite set $\{n_i,m_i\}_{I=1}^{k}$ with $n_i,m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$\gamma = S^{n_1}T^{m_1} \cdots S^{n_k}T^{m_k}$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $n_i \in \{1,3\}$ for $i\neq 1$ and $0 \le n_1 \le 3$. Similarly, we can assume that $m_i \neq 0$ for $i\neq k$.

> Under which assumptions, if there are any, we can assume the above factorization of $\gamma$ unique?

Just to be precise, let $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be written in the two following way

$\gamma = S^{n_1}T^{m_1} \cdots S^{n_k}T^{m_k}, \quad \gamma=S^{\bar{n_1}}T^{\bar{m_1}} \cdots S^{\bar{n_k}}T^{\bar{m_k}}.$

We say that a factorization of the element $\gamma$ is unique we can conclude that $n_i = \bar{n}_i$ and $m_i = \bar{m}_i$.

Comment: Observe that $S^2=-I$ is in the center, so you really should have that $0\leq n_1\leq 3$, and the other $n_i=1$, and even after making that adjustment, I'd have to think a bit about this unique factorization, but my gut tells me there isn't a unique factorization

Comment: Sure, I'm editing this right now.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197537/prove-that-psl2-mathbbz-is-free-product-of-c-2-and-c-3 .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is unique factorization since there is one way to think of $S$ and $T$ generating $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}$ is by doing the Euclidean algorithm, and since we can either do the classic Euclidean algorithm or a signed Euclidean algorithm, this should lead to $2$ different factorizations.
Since we have that
$$
S\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-c & -d\\a & b\end{bmatrix}
$$
while
$$
T^m\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c &d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a+mc & b+md\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$

For example, let us consider
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then we can observe that doing the classical Euclidean algorithm we have that
$$
T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
ST^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -2\\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
T^2ST^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
ST^2ST^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
T^2ST^2ST^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=S
$$
From this we get one factorization of
$$
X=TS^3T^{-2}S^3T^{-2}S=TST^{-2}ST^{-2}S
$$
Now we can give another factorization  doing the Euclidean algorithm as
$$
T^{-2}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
ST^{-2}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
T^{-3}ST^{-2}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
ST^{-3}ST^{-2}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=T
$$
Thus, this calculation gives us
$$
X=T^2S^3T^3S^3T=T^2ST^3ST
$$
which is a different factorization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think the two presentations are really different: let us keep in mind that the element $S^2$ is central then $T^2S^3T^3S^3T = T^2 S S^2 T^3 S S^2 T = S^2 S^2 T^2S T^3 S T=T^2S T^3 S T$. Maybe if we assume all the $n_i$, with $ i\neq 1$, to be $1$ and we don't allow any part to be equal to $(ST)^3$, the factorization becomes unique.

Comment: Aren't my two factorizations $X=T^2ST^3ST$ and $X=TST^{-2}ST^{-2}S$ which I don't think you showed are different, but I think the comment linking to the stack exchange post shows that $\mathbb{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the free product of $C_2$ and $C_3$ says that there should be a ``unique'' factorization in $S$ and $ST$.